# Reincarnation confuses me

Tags: consciousness

There's the theory of reincarnation, which means that when you die, will be reborn as a different person. My problem with this is that it confuses me that we won't have any of the memories from that time. For instance, I could say that my consciousness was there in the 1800s with a different person, but I'd be confusing myself because then I'd ask myself why I'm not back then right now. To which I reply that that's because I'm in 2015 right now with no recollection whatsoever of life in the 1800s, but then it goes in a loop in my mind, so if anyone knows about any clarification or wants to speculate too, I'm open to all ideas.

Comment: Perhaps when you are between worlds you recover you're identity as a single unitary being; still reincarnation is an idea more associated with Indian philosophy than Western - it's probably best looking there.

Comment: Actually reincarnation was a fairly common concept in the West until it was deemed heretical by one of the early church councils. But I think it would be better answered if the question was not closed but moved by a moderator to Hinduism SE.

Comment: But I wasn't asking regarding Hinduism. I was asking in general. Many religions have a theory of reincarnation, but I'm not trying ask a religion-based question. Just a general one regarding the idea of reincarnation without any religious or ideological ties, and I thought that Philosophy seemed to best suit those parameters.

Answer (score 2):

There must be something that gives content to the assertion that I and that person from 1800 are *the same person* . Since we do not inhibit the same body, the common factor should probably be in the memories. Here are two related excerpts from [John Locke's classical memory theory of personal identity](http://www.gutenberg.org/catalog/world/readfile?pageno=205&fk_files=3276103):

> 19. Self depends on Consciousness, not on Substance.
>       SELF is that conscious thinking thing,--whatever substance made up
>       of, (whether spiritual or material, simple or compounded, it matters
>       not)--which is sensible or conscious of pleasure and pain, capable of
>       happiness or misery, and so is concerned for itself, as far as that
>       consciousness extends. Thus every one finds that, whilst comprehended
>       under that consciousness, the little finger is as much a part of himself
>       as what is most so. Upon separation of this little finger, should this
>       consciousness go along with the little finger, and leave the rest of
>       the body, it is evident the little finger would be the person, the same
>       person; and self then would have nothing to do with the rest of the
>       body . . .
> 20. Which shows wherein Personal identity consists.
>       This may show us wherein personal identity consists: not in the identity
>       of substance, but, as I have said, in the identity of consciousness,
>       wherein if Socrates and the present mayor of Queenborough agree, they
>       are the same person . . .

From what I've heard personally I think that reincarnation theories usually involve the belief that past lives *can* be remembered, in principle, even though they usually aren't remembered. That is, if you are properly gifted, or properly trained, you will recall your past lives. There is a lot of internet material about reincarnation memories. See for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Past_life_regression).